# javascript link makes the page go up onclick

Tags: javascript, wordpress, popup

I have a problem in my website, 
I have build a menu that consist of javascript links, 
When i click on link from the menu, the page goes up, 
You can see it here:

http://www.ourevent.co.il/dj-%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%99%D7%91-%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%AA

I never saw it before, anyone have an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample? And isolate the problem in a fiddle.

Comment: Also first guess would be to check your `href` attribute on your links. You probably have `href="#"` when you should have `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Answer (score 0):

This probably means you have a javascript error somewhere else, or you are using  tags with an href of "#" and not using event.preventDefault() in your click method. I would check the console for javascript errors, or ensure your click event is using preventDefault.

ex:

```
$('a.neat-link').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  /* do your link stuff here and it should work */ 
})
```